# How to avoid high memory usage in Phaser game using Cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, phaser-framework

I have developed a Cordova Phaser game. It runs in Android and iOS devices.

The game has seven levels, with each level having a number of sprite (background, player) and groups (bullets, enemies).

In `preload` function, I have loaded all images and atlasJSONHash

```
function preload(){
    game.load.atlasJSONHash('anim', 'anim.png', 'anim.json');
    //and so on
}

function create(){
     var star = game.add.sprite(160, 32, 'level1bg');
     star.x = 0;
     star.y = 0;
     star.height = game.height;
     star.width = game.width;

     bullets = game.add.group();
     bullets.enableBody = true;
     bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

     bullets.createMultiple(30, 'bullet');
     bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
     bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 1);
     bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
     bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);
     //and so on
}
function startlevel(level)
{
     var star = game.add.sprite(160, 32, 'level1bg');
     star.x = 0;
     star.y = 0;
     star.height = game.height;
     star.width = game.width;

     bullets = game.add.group();
     bullets.enableBody = true;
     bullets.physicsBodyType = Phaser.Physics.ARCADE;

     bullets.createMultiple(30, 'bullet');
     bullets.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
     bullets.setAll('anchor.y', 1);
     bullets.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
     bullets.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);
     //and so on
}
```

When the level ends I call `startlevel(2)` and so on.

In browser it runs fine, but in mobile memory doubles for each level, with the app eventually crashing. How do I avoid this memory problem?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this would help. Before assign a new group, to make sure old group is destroyed, I always call destroy on it and then re-assign a new group.
Move over i think you will want to create a new function for init your bullets group and re-use it.

```
function createBulletGroup(){

    if(bullets!=null)
    { 
         bullets.destroy(true);
         bullets = null; 
    }
    //.. The rest of add group
}
```

More over, since you use

```
var star = game.add.sprite(160, 32, 'level1bg');
```

Every time you startlevel, a new star will be placed on the old star, since their position are the same. When star is created, it will be assigned to world. And re-create star many time cause memory leak which can't be seen by eyes.

You can try to randomly place your star when you start new level too see if it overlapped others or set it alpha to 0.5;

Comment: Am I understand correctly that we should always set NULL ref after destroy? 
Seems like Phaser just cleaning up props in sprites but not removing objects